# Display child terms of taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

When displaying a taxonomy term, how can I also display the teasers of all the child terms of the current term?  I still want to display all the content and fields of the current node, but also display the child teasers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taxonomy display won't do this on its own. You could create a view to do this, then display the view below the term page.

If you call the view from a taxonomy term template you could use a "Contextual filter" to pass the term id (tid).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  As far as I understand it now, this is only possible by overriding the taxonomy-term.tpl.php with some custom PHP.  If that's the case, why not just do it all withing the custom theme template, and skip the View?

Comment: After reading the template module source code, looking for functions that do what I want, I came up with this.

    $terms = taxonomy_get_children($term->tid, $vid);
    $a = taxonomy_term_view_multiple($terms, 'teaser');
    echo drupal_render($a);

Does that seem reasonable?